# ParseException goes directly to catch

Tags: java, try-catch, simpledateformat, parseexception

My `SimpleDateFormat` keeps throwing a `ParseException`. I can’t get it to actually get into the try block, it just keeps going directly to my catch. Any idea what is wrong in my code?

```
public static String getEventDate() throws ParseException {
    System.out.println("When is the date of your event? (dd/MM/yyyy)");
    String date = in.nextLine();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date eventDate = null;
    try {
        eventDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Error in date format");
    }

    String finalDate = dateFormat.format(eventDate);
    return finalDate;

}




public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Event event = getEventInfo();
    System.out.println(event);

}
public static Event getEventInfo() throws ParseException {
    String eventType = getEventType();
    String eventDate = getEventDate();
    Event event = new Event(eventType, eventDate);
    return event;
}
```

Comment: We need a little more info: What's your input? What's your expected output? Can you include the output of the console please?

Comment: yeah sorry, i'd like to get the user to type in a date. then i want to save in and return it to my Event object that has a constructor to take in two strings, it tells me Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, but i guess this is because i try to access the field of a null object (because it never get to the try block)

Comment: I cannot reproduce. When I enter `25/12/2017` at the prompt, your program prints the event and terminates with no sign of any exception (I declared `in` and a very simple `Event` class myself).

Comment: A tip not related (probably not related) to your issue, the classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`are long outdated and often cumbersome to work with. Do yourself the favour of reading about [the modern Java date & time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and then use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` instead.

Comment: Fairly nice question for a newcomer on Stack Overflow, by the way. Your code example is almost minimal and almost complete, only not verifiable. Next time you will want to read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and do even better.

Comment: Ole V.V. I read another thread that said it could have something to do with my environmental variables being set wrong or just different, if it works for you, then that might be the case, and thanks alot for the Link, ill take a look at it :)

Comment: The new LocalDate and DateTimeFormatter, do they work exactly like Date and SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: Real weird, ive tried restarting from scratch, as according to your link, now with this code and a scanner in and the simple Event class, i get no errors.

Comment: I've fixed it! by replacing in.nextLine with just in.next, any clue why this worked?

Comment: I fail to see how `in.next()` solved the problem. If I enter something that is not a date (like my name), I get `Error in date format` and then a `NullPointerException` because `eventDate` is still null. But the same happens with `in.next()`.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally typed an error in your date before, like letter l instead of digit 1 or letter O instead of digit 0 or hyphens instead of slashes. Then when you type a correct date now and it works, you think it’s because of the change in the code when it isn’t.

Comment: No, the modern classes don’t work exactly the same as the outdated ones. Generally they work better, have a better design, are nicer to work with, more programmer friendly.

Comment: Anyhow, i'll take a look into the new date classes, and hopefully wont meet this problem again. You've been a great help Ole, both overflow wise and codewise, thank you for your time :)